# ConcurrentModificationException after subList()

Tags: java, unit-testing

I'm running into this problem in a unit test.

After executing:

```
List<Card> cleanCards = cards.subList(0, cards.size() - difference);
```

the following assert gives me a ConcurrentModificationException:

```
assertEquals(limit, cleanCards.size());
```

Error description

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException 
at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.size(ArrayList.java:1057)
```

To my knowledge, the 'size()' method does not make structural changes to the list. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely the original list is being modified between the sub-list creation and its use. `subList` does not create an independent new list, but rather a view of a section of the original list, and as the [specs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList(int,%20int)) say

> The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if
>   the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified in any way
>   other than via the returned list. (Structural modifications are those
>   that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a
>   fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.)

and in your case, the "undefined" behaviour seems to result in an exception being thrown, also known as *fail-fast behaviour*. I reckon an easy solution would be to change the first line above to

```
List<Card> cleanCards = new ArrayList<>(cards.subList(0, cards.size() - difference));
```

which copies the sub-list to a completely new list independent of the original.